# Explanation of 歌にのせて

Tags: grammar, words

From JapanesePod101, with their translation:

ミュージカルは、歌【うた】にのせて物語【ものがたり】を展開【てんかい】する。
A musical can tell a story with songs.

I understand that のせる means (amongst other things) "to take on board". Does 歌にのせて mean something like the musical is "riding on" (i.e. conveyed by) songs? Also, what is the direct object of the transitive のせて?

Comment: This is easier to understand when you change the word order:  ミュージカルは、物語を歌にのせて展開する。

Comment: That is indeed easier, thanks! It's confusing to put 物語を after the first verb it modifies (のせて).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct object of のせて is 物語, and the sentence means "the musical evolves the story putting it on the songs".

Comment: I think your interpretation of the Japanese is correct, but your English could use some polishing. How about `A musical develops a story by dressing it in song.`? Or otherwise just `A musical develops a story (through / by means of) song`. The verb "evolve" is intransitive, and putting stuff *on* top of songs sounds odd in English. Same goes for the lack of a conjunction (e.g., "by").